# Oracle SQL - Remove double records that differ to one column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, grouping

I have a select query that returns 30+ fields and I found out that there are some double records that differ to exactly one field. The problem look like:

```
select t1.field1, t2.field2 
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
 where t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key
 group by t1.field1, t2.field2;
```

(don't mind the join, it is cross checked and it works fine)

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | field1| field2   |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 |(null) | 20       |
|  2 |SValue | 20       |
```

In the first the field is null and in the second the field contains a string. I completely want to remove the null record.

I tried to `select max(t1.field1)` and `select nvl(t1.field1)` but nothing changed.
I also tried to `select max(t1.field1) over (partition by t2.field2)` but the result was (despite the group by) exactly the same record twice, like:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | field1| field2   |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 |SValue | 20       |
|  2 |SValue | 20       |
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: I see two additional variations, can you tell me what you want the results to be for these?  First, what if the value for <field2> when field1 is null does not match other values of <field2>?  Second, do you want the reverse operation as well, that is, when <field2> has a null?

Comment: I have noticed that the values for field2 matches all the time with the rest and I don't need the reverse at the moment.

Comment: You're making an assumption that will not work as the application grows.  I can help you with what you asked, but advise you to consider all the cases.

Comment: I can see what you are saying and I will try a completely different approach to my problem. But just for my curiosity, can you propose something if it is not a big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  field1, field2
from (
  select 
    field2, 
    field1,
    rank () over (partition by field2 order by field1 desc nulls last) as fld1_rank,
    coalesce (field1, max (field1) over (partition by field2 order by field1 desc nulls last)) as field1_find,
    count (*) over (partition by field2) as entries_with_field2
  from (
    with 
      t1 as (
        select 't1f1a' as field1, 'pk1' as primary_key from dual
        union all select to_char(null) as field1, '1' as primary_key from dual
        union all select 'SValue' as field1, '2' as primary_key from dual
      ),
      t2 as (
        select 1111 as field2, 'pk1' as primary_key from dual
        union all select 20 as field2, '1' as primary_key from dual
        union all select 20 as field2, '2' as primary_key from dual
      )
    select * 
    from 
      t1 join t2 using (primary_key)
  ) baseresult
  group by
    field1, field2
) ranked
where
  field1 is not null or
  entries_with_field2 = 1
;
```